# How add style to a div outside of a button

Tags: css

I want add a style to a div without class and id.

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 4px;">
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="cancelParty();">×</button>
</div>
```

I'm Try the next :

```
div.close{position:relative!important;}
div<.close{position:relative!important;}
div>.close{position:relative!important;}
```

and nothing.

Comment: This looks just completely wrong? Or is it just me?

Comment: what issue do you have? can you to explain more clearly?

Comment: If you are using jquery try the .parent() property. Here is more info. https://api.jquery.com/parent/. And if you are not then there is a parentElement selector in plain Javascript.. Here is more info on that one. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp

Comment: Try `div .close` (with a space on between) or `div button.close` or just `.close`